# Django - how to create and use context processors / the variables which the context processors return

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, processors

Along with my

```
settings.py
```

and

```
urls.py
```

file, I created a

```
context_processors.py
```

file in the same directory. This is my context_processors.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def loginFormCustom(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return {'loginForm': form,}
```

and this is my views.py:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from tp.context_processors import loginFormCustom

def main_page(request):

    variables = { 'title': 'This is the title of the page' }
    return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors = loginFormCustom))
```

Now, when I run this and go to The URL which calls the main_page view, it gives me a TypeError at / saying:

```
'function' object is not iterable
```

and the traceback leads to this:

```
return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors = loginFormCustom))
```

any idea why? Am I using the context processor correctly?

Comment: It seems like you are asking 2 questions.  Can you log in Special users separately than new users?  And can you put a Login Form on several templates without having to write all of the Form view code each time?  Is that correct?

Comment: @AronYsidoro sorry, I just edited the post and went a lot more specific. I figured out my real problem and edited the post to reflect my real problem. I basically want to use the variables which loginFormCustom returns, I want to use those variables in my main_page view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django Docs say that the AuthenticationForm is just that, it is a Form, so I believe that you would need to call it in this way:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def main_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    # log in user, etc...
  else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()  # Unbound Form

  return render(request, 'main_page.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'form': AuthenticationForm}))
```

Comment: hm okay, I can also do "else: form=AuthenticationForm() variables = {'form': form } return render(request, 'main_page.html', variables)" instead right? And I won't even need the RequestContext?

Comment: Yes that is correct, but I believe RequestContext allows you access to the context processors functions / methods in Django.  I'd read more on the Django Docs on this and what kind of extra functions AuthenticationForm comes with.

Comment: by the way, do you know why my loginFormCustom context processor and why exactly it said that "'function' object is not iterable"? What is it trying to iterate to? I thought that if I do "processors = loginFormCustom" then it will grab all the variables which the loginFormCustom returns?

Comment: I'd read more on the Django Docs about context processors.  I'm haven't used them too extensively so far. thnx

Comment: RequestContext Deprecated since version 1.8.