# Django ModelForm isn`t saving data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form for subscribing in footer.html that is included in base.html, so the form should work at every page on the site. I used context_processor solution for this and everything works fine, however data are not saving in DB for some reason. I spent hours with looking for proper solution on Stack but did`nt make it saving.

Similar question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150834/django-how-to-create-and-use-context-processors-the-variables-which-the-cont), but also doesnt work for me. Should be something simple, but as Im new to django, got a little bit complicated with this.
Please help. Thanks in advance

*Note: Be sure, **'catalogue.context_processors.SubscribeFormGlobal'** is added to settings*

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models


class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import Subscriber


class SubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        fields = ('email',)
```

*context_processors.py*

```
from .forms import SubscriberForm


def SubscribeFormGlobal(request):
    return {'subscribe_form': SubscriberForm()}
```

*views.py*

```
def subscribe_us(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subscribe_form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
        if subscribe_form.is_valid():
            subscribe_form.save(commit=False)
            subscribe_form.author = request.user
            subscribe_form.published_date = timezone.now()
            subscribe_form.save()
    else:
        subscribe_form = SubscriberForm()
    return render(request, '', {'subscribe_form': subscribe_form})
```

*urls.py*

```
from catalogue import views
from catalogue.models import Bancnote

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.bons_list, name='bons_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Bancnote, template_name='catalogue/bon_detail.html')),
    url(r'^feedback/$', views.feedback, name='feedback'),
    url(r'^$', views.subscribe_us, name='subscribe')
]
```

*footer.html*

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block footer %}
    <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <i style="color:#f84c48; margin-top: -10px" class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-5x"
                           aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <p id="text-email">Test</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <form action="{% url 'subscribe' %}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                {{ subscribe_form.as_p }}        
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" style="background:#1d6e87; color: white; border: 0"
                                        class="btn btn-default">Subscriber</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <hr style="margin: 10px 0; border-color: #d6d6d6">
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <h4>Contacts</h4>
                        <p>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker contacts"></i>
                            Test
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <i class="fa fa-phone contacts"></i>
                            Test
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope contacts"></i>
                            WCUB@gmail.com
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur error quidem sit velit? A,
                        ab, animi aut culpa ea eos ex illo itaque iure nisi officiis quasi quia soluta veritatis!
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div id="social-networks">
                            <h4>Social Networks</h4>
                            <a href="https://vk.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://facebook.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two views with the same URL pattern - you have both bons_list and subscribe at the root URL. This means that only the bons_list view is ever called.

You need to give subscribe its own URL.

(When you do this, you'll get an error on submit because of the empty template name in the `render` call; not sure why you are doing that, you need to provide a template to render when the form is not valid. You should also redirect when it *is* valid; presumably you would redirect back to the home page.)

Comment: oh this really works! I skiped that field in render, cause I need to stay on the same page after submitting, do you know how could this being done? I   have read that <form action='.'> can do this but in this case I will not access my view

Comment: nevermind, I found this  return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER']), but now I noticed that my form doesnt show up at some pages, main page, and object detailed page are showin it, but feedback page not. Could it be something with urls again ?

Comment: nevermind agaig, should be usin render insted of render_to_response

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here in your urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.bons_list, name='bons_list'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Bancnote, template_name='catalogue/bon_detail.html')),
url(r'^feedback/$', views.feedback, name='feedback'),
url(r'^$', views.subscribe_us, name='subscribe')
```

The way django matches urls it will match the first regex that matches the request. The way your urls.py is written the subscribe view is never called. You will need a different url to post the request to for this to work.

Comment: thank you for answering, do u know how to specify returning of current page in render after form submitting?

Comment: nevermind, found this  return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])